# Transform does not have a definition for position and An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StartCombat : MonoBehaviour

{   if(Transform.Position.y > 1)
        {
            Transform.Translate(0f, -2.5f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Unity keeps telling me that Transform does not have a definition for position and An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Transform.Translate(float, float, float)

All I am trying to do is have an image slide in from the top of the screen for my game

Comment: ... you need a method around this e.g. `private void Update(){ if(Pos.Position.y > 1)
        {
            Trasform.Translate(0f, -2.5f, 0f);
        }
    } }` also I guess you would want to replace both `Pos` and `Transform` by `transform` ... there is no `Pos` or `Transform` defined in your code ... and `Transform` itself is a **class** while `transform` is a property of `MonoBehaviour` ...

Comment: Did you mean `transform.position` and `transform.Translate`?

Comment: Why don't you start with a simple standalone Console C# program to get a feeling for how things are done in C#?

Comment: Please note that your question title should describe the problem you're facing, it shouldn't describe the product you're making or be biographical.

Comment: Agreed. Using a framework to teach yourself is often the wrong approach. Learn the standard library, the syntax, classes, and best practices (including unit testing), then learn about a framework (Unity, Blazor, ASP, WinForms etc)

Comment: Please see [`Component.transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) .. there even is exactly your example ;) Note that `have an image slide in` .. this won't happen with the code you have there ... It will jump immediately to `y = -1.5` since you translate it hard about `-2.5` units ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was capital letters where they werent supposed to be specifically the transform and position were supposed to be lowercase.